How do I tell Delphi to use the correct list separator in the Watch List?
The following applies at least for Delphi 2007 and Delphi 10.2.
When debugging a Delphi application, the Watch List is one of my most used features. Unfortunately, it mixes language-specific formatting when displaying arrays and records of floats. On a German Windows with Delphi configured to English, this leads to the following display of a two-field record:

As you can see, this looks a bit confusing when you display it as one line only.
In German, the decimal separator is "," and the list separator is ";", while English uses "." and "," respectively. So, the output is a mix of German (Windows) and English (Delphi default or Delphi IDE language).
Unfortunately, I don't know how to change the IDE language in Delphi 2007. But in Delphi 10.2, changing the IDE language doesn't make a difference, neither for the decimal nor the list separator.
Is there a way to tell Delphi to use either English or German separators only in the Watch List so it looks like one of the below ways and not a mix of both?
(0.1, 0.1) 
(0,1; 0,1)


Yes, that's definitely a bug in the Delphi IDE. And it still exists in Delphi 12. No, there is no configuration option to change this. It always uses the decimal separator from Windows regional options and mixes it with a comma (hardcoded) as list separator. (Personally ( would prefer it to always use a decimal point.)

This sounds like an Embarcadero issue, I would suggest submitting a request to https://qp.embarcadero.com so it can be considered for future versions.
The only other option I can think of is to change the Windows language to English.  This way your watches would at least show as (0.1, 0.1) and be less confusing.

No need to switch the language, just change the decimal separator in Regional Options. (And file a bug report as suggested.)

I created a EQP ticket:
https://embt.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1/RSS-1344
